# Swift - View and Use Terminal Inside Another Application

Tags: swift, macos, terminal

I'm trying to build an application (MyApp) for macOS that integrates the Terminal app.

Is it possible to open Terminal from inside a MyApp window (or even better, an element inside the window) and run commands and view the output? Or does this require building a new command line tool to run inside MyApp? I want to be able to edit files and run commands without switching between apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [`NSWorkspace` class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchApplication).

Do
`NSWorkspace().launchApplication("Terminal")`

Or if you're programming for MacOS 10.15 and later where `NSWorkspace` is deprecated, do

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", isDirectory: true) as URL

let path = "/bin"
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = [path]
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                   configuration: configuration,
                                   completionHandler: nil)
```